# ASP Net Chart control bar height

Tags: asp.net, charts, height, bar-chart

On an ASP.NET web project, I have a stackedbar100 chart like this:

[image]

The height of the chart is set to 50px, but like you see there is a grey part showing.

What I would like to do is to make the green bar occupy all 50px and no grey part.

I've seen all the chart properties but haven't found the one that does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok... Found this option under:

Chart -> Properties -> Chart Areas -> Axes -> Scale -> IsMarginVisible -> False

Repeated for each axis

Ok, to remove the left and right margins:

Chart -> Properties -> Chart Areas -> Position -> Set Height and Width to 100%

Thanks